Use appsettings.json from build instead from root
i used SlowCheetah to create transformation for my appsettings.json to change the connection string for each build type.
Here is how i'm loading the json:
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

but, it istill reading the default appsettings.json. I found in {root}/obj/{BuildType} path, the file transformed correctly, but i think the program is reading it from root.
There is some way to read the transformed file without using ASPNETCORE_ENVIROMENT?
obs: i don't want to use the enviroment because my variations already are based on build type

Update: I've tried to build the publish version and the final file in the folder was changed like i need. Although in debug mode it always use the default version, it not looks to be a problem when publish. When i publish in production i will post the solution
